# Add element span without changing the position of existing centered elements

Tags: html, css, center

this is my first topic here, I've already tried some solutions for my scenario but withou success, so I think I could use some help:

I'm working in a existing html page and I'm intern, so I need to change without modifying anything else (or at least the minimum).

So here's my problem:

```
<form action="">
<center>
<div class="example-class">
  <input type="text" id="example3" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <input type="text" id="example2" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
  <input type="text" id="example2" name="lname" value="Example"><span>myText</span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</center>
</form>
```

In the code above the elements are showed centered.
I want to add some text, like "myText" of span tag, when I click the button in the right side of an input element , but when I try to do this, the input element loses the "align" of others inputs (it comes left). So how can I add this "span text" but keep the input elements aligned?

- I need to avoid changing the others elements css.

Im attaching an example code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#myText").show();
        return false;
    })
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<style>
input{
width: 92%;
text-align: center;
align: left;
align-items: start;
}

.example-class{
        width: 400px;
        height:300px;
        padding:5%;
}

.myText{
display:none;
}

</style>

<h2>Example</h2>

<form action="">
<center>
<div class="example-class">
  <input type="text" id="example3" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <input type="text" id="example2" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
  <input type="text" id="example2" name="lname" value="Example"><span class="myText" id="myText">!!!</span><br>
  <button id="button">Show element</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</center>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically want to add myText next to the value of the input?

Like in your example, it would become "Example !!!" in the input box.

In that case just use javascript. Get the current input value and append myText to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#button").click(function(){
        let myText = '!!!'
        let currentValue = $("#example2").val();
        $("#example2").val(currentValue + ' ' + myText)
        return false;
    })
   });
```

// EDIT (I understand more clearly what you want after your comment)

You could play around with `position: relative` and `position: absolute` in your css.

```
  .example-class{
        position:relative;  // add this
         width: 400px;
        height:300px;
        padding:5%;
  }

.myText{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; // add this
  right: 80px; // play with this one. 
}
```

Normally that should do the trick.

Comment: I want to add another element to the right side of the input element, you can ignore the text value "Example". The function of add element is working properly, but if you notice, when the span element is showed, the input element goes more to the left and don't be align to the others input anymore. I just want to add the element and keep the same position of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Set position absolute to your span

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#myText").show();
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 92%;
  text-align: center;
  align: left;
  align-items: start;
}

.example-class {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 5%;
}

.myText {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /*<-- the change */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Example</h2>
<form action="">
  <center>
    <div class="example-class">
      <input type="text" id="example3" name="fname" value="John"><br>
      <input type="text" id="example2" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
      <input type="text" id="example2" name="lname" value="Example"><span class="myText" id="myText">!!!</span><br>
      <button id="button">Show element</button>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
```